# Error with PrincipalPermission authentication in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, security

I am following a [Pluralsight video on Authentication](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=wcf-design-concepts&highlight=aaron-skonnard_serialization%2a1).

I am trying to add simple PrinciplePermission authentication to my web service:

```
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Computer\\Group")]
    public String testDBConnection()
    {
        return "success";  
    }
```

In my WCF client I am sending:

```
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Alice";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "alice";
```

I have created the group and added Alice to it as per the video, but now....

I keep getting the error:

**"Request for principal permission failed."**

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: When sending the username and password using the `ClientCredentials`, I recently noticed that information wasn't available in the `Thread.CurrentPrinciple` on the server side. The `PrinciplePermission` uses the `Thread.CurrentPrinciple` to validate the user. I don't know if you can configure this.

Comment: @Steven thanks for your reply, I'm sorry I don't know what Thread.CurrentPriciple is, could you give more details please?

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentPrincipel` returns an `IPrincipal` instance, which is often the `WindowsPrincipel`. This contains information of the current user who's running the thread.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  I'm seeing the same error

Comment: @Stephen Nutt I ended up taking a different approach because all I needed was simple username password authentication. Looking back I suspect it might be because I didn't have an SSL certificate, because they do in the video and later on, this turned out to be essential for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need some code to create the `IPrincipal` on the server when the request arrives.

The easiest way to do this is probably to use an ASP.NET `RoleProvider`, for which you need to configure a behaviour, e.g.:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ...
  <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name=...>
           ...
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"
                        roleProviderName="MyRoleProvider" />
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
     ...
```

and:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="MyRoleProvider" 
      ...
```

If you configure a `RoleProvider` correctly in this way, then `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` will be set automagically, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The principle object is a read only object that gets set as part of the security settings for your application upon loading. The way I was able to get around it was to create a class that inherits IPrincipal. You would need to do this in your WCF application.